# created vector in qgis by using delimited text file

Tags: python, qgis

I'm using qgis python to import the Planet format GIS data.

Planet example:

```
1(number)   CONSTRUCTION(type)    5(number of point to describe this polygon)
209945.23 2469136.12
209922.30 2469133.28
209918.89 2469160.82
209941.82 2469163.66
209945.23 2469136.12
2           CONSTRUCTION           5
209983.99 2469091.87
209950.50 2469073.53
209932.20 2469106.95
209965.69 2469125.29
209983.99 2469091.87
...
...
...
```

Someone have any idea of how to create it by using:

```
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, "layer_name_you_like", "delimitedtext")
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this sites.

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/156247/how-to-read-non-spatial-data-using-pyqgis

http://docs.qgis.org/2.0/pl/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/loadlayer.html

before loading your file Gis data in Qgis,you need preprocess this file.